# How do I group concat each row?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, group-concat

I have this query

```
SELECT 1 as row, array_agg(id) as ids FROM users GROUP BY row;
```

Results

```
  row  |   ids
---------------
  1     {1,2,3,4}
```

I have a lot more results that can't fit in one row...so I'm trying to build a query that does this:

```
  row  |   ids
---------------
  1     {1,3,4,5}
  2     {4,6,9,20}
  3     {21,24,26,30}
  etc.....
```

I want to limit the ids to say 50 per row with as many rows as possible. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I think you'll need to provide some sample input data to go with this. See http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Maybe I did a bad explanation, but the input data doesn't really matter. I just want to select ALL available ids in a table and display them vertically, but limit the vertical results by 50. So this is a mixture of vertical and horizontal results.

Comment: To continue my previous comment..Say we have 1000 ids in the user table, so we will have 50 ids in each row, which makes that 20 rows (50x20=1000). The row column is just for show, it doesn't really matter. I think this is a weird query, but I need it lol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`row_number() over()` returns the row number. Then just do a subquery to group them together. Change `4` to the number you actually want

```
select a.r, array_agg(a.id) ids
from (
  select (row_number() over()-1)/4 r, id
  from users) a
group by a.r;
```

demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5c738/22

Comment: Holy cow!! This is exactly what I wanted!